# How to implement tiered pricing based on weight or cube volume or order amount total into objective function with Guro i py

Tags: optimization, gurobi

I am working on an optimization project here and my objective is to come out with the optimal amount of each item to buy at certain vendors that can minimize the cost while meeting the demand(already figured out the demand constraints).

Here is a little background for the case below, there are 2 Vendors, 2 distribution centers(DC), 2 items(UPC), and 2 Microfulfillment centers (MFC) and the chart below also contains the price, weight, and cube of each item.

In my model, there are two types of variables:

1. first type is a continuous variable where it has a form of v_dc_u_m(ex: v1_dc1_u1_m1 = 5 means 5 unit of items 1 purchased from vendor 1, shipping from dc1 to mfc1), it will be like
2. second type of variable is a binary variable that has a form of v_dc_m which is used for calculating freight fee(ex: v1_dc1_m1 = 1 means a shipment is processed from v1, dc1 to m1, then it will be charged the corresponding freight fee)

The freight cost of each vendor(v1, v2) is also below where v1 charges a freight fee based on the total weight and cube of all ordered items from one DC to one MFC; v2 charges a freight fee based on the total order amount(in $) from one DC to one MFC.

Everything else for this model is done except for this complicated freight cost in the objective function. I am stuck on this part and would really appreciate some help on how to implement this freight fee idea.

I do have an idea, in the objective part, loop through all the unique v_mfc combinations and then sum up the total weight and cube of all ordered items from one DC to one MFC(using gp.quicksum()), then use multiple if-else statements to compare with the cube and weight range and use the corresponding freight fee. The same idea applies to v2 where it is based on the total order amount in dollars.

Would really want some advice on whether my idea will work OR if anyone can share an easier way to implement this idea would be greatly appreciated!
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a decent research, I found that the tiered order amount can be implemented easily by using "Model.addGenConstrPWL()" from gurobi which is a general constraints for Piecewise function.

Below is a link for anyone that wants to take a look!

https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/py_model_agc_pwl.html

Also, another useful link is below if your piecewise function input is the sum of other variables:

https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360077610571-A-weird-output-is-it-a-bug-of-Gurobi-8-1-1-

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if-then-else with indicator constraints will work.
If you may linearize, here's the suggestion
Suppose $0 \le x_{v,d,m,u,w,c} \in Z$ is integer number of items $u$ ordered from vendor $v$ DC, of weight $w$ & volume $c$
Also define some binary cost variables $v1_i$ where $i= {1,2,...6}$ scenarios. Also depending upon the problem it seems vendor $v1$ has created a tiered pricing based on either weight or cube volume. Every item $x$ will have a weight/cube. Weight/cube is given in the table ${0.7,1.13}$ & weight ${5.5,9.4}$. So you can derive the minimum numbers of items that is causing this tier system, like from freight chart for vendor $v1$, total weight=500, each weight $=5.5$, so minimum order $500/5.5$. Same for cube $999/0.7$.
Then perhaps vendor is looking at minimum of min$\{500/5.5,999/0.7,500/9.4,999/1.13\}$. Suppose this number is VQ[1]. Likewise you may need to recreate a table of minimum quantity of $x$ for each threshold. It will be 6 scenarios with 6 freight cost $VC_i=Cost_i*VQ_i$. Also $200$ at 0 weight, 0 cube, looks like setup cost which needs to be added. 
Same for vendor 2, define binary variable $v2_j$ where $j={1,2,..5}$ scenarios. Its more straight forward, depending upon value of items ordered from DC to MFC.

Constraints:
$\forall i$:
(1)  $\sum_{d,m,w,c,u}(x_{v1,d,m,u,w,c} 
 \le VQ_i+Mv1_i$
(2)  $VQ_i \le \sum_{d,m,w,c,u}x_{v1,d,m,u,w,c}+M(1-v1_i)$

Combining constr (1)&(2) into single pair of constraints
(3) $ \sum_iVQ_iv1_i \le \sum_{d,m,w,c,u}x_{v1,d,m,w,c,u} \le \sum_i VQ_{i+1}v1_i$

(4) $\sum_i v1_i = 1$

Gurobi expression
$VC1 = 200 + \sum_i V1C_iv1_i$: It will select one of the freight costs depending upon the volume.

For vendor 2:
$\forall j$:
(5)  $\sum_{d,m,w,c,u}p_{v2,d,m,u, w,c}x_{v2,d,m,w,c,u}  \le V2C_j+Mv2_j$ 
(6) $VC_j \le \sum_{d,m,w,c,u}p_{v2,d,m,u,w,c}x_{v2,d,m,w,c,u} + M(1-v2_j)$

Combining constrs (5)&(6) into a pair of constraints as above
(7) $\sum_j V2C_jv2_j \sum_{dmwcu}p_{v2,d,m,u,w,c}x_{v2,d,m,w,c,u} \le \sum_j V2C_{j+1}v2_j$
(8) $\sum_jv2_j = 1$
$M$ can be big enough number, like upper bound of $x$.

Gurobi expression
$VC2 = \sum_jV2C_jv2_j$: It will select one of the freight costs depending upon the order price.

Comment: By indicator constraints, do you mean constraints that contain binary variables?

Comment: Yes, Gurobi already has inbuilt indicator constraints for python, java, c++

Comment: I think I am a bit lost on the purpose of deriving the minimum number of items that are causing the tier system.  Do you mind clarifying this? From my understanding, once the total weight and cube are calculated, I will just need to compare the number with a dictionary or table that has the information to extract the corresponding fee.  I feel like your approach is working backward(Like first calculating the threshold) which is different than mine.

Comment: Since we are trying to save cost, I am guessing this is the reason why you want to pick the minimum of min{500/5.5,999/0.7,500/9.4,999/1.13}, I also have a demand number that I need to meet and I already have that implemented, I am guessing as long as I get this part done, then my model should be able to pick the cheapest options on the freight for v1 and v2 and meet the demand at the same time right?

Comment: Yes, once order volume $x$ is calculated indicator constraint will pickup the right cost to apply. But in optimization you can't straight away use if-then statements involving decision variables like $x$. For that you either need to use indicator variables or introduce linear constraints using binary variables. These binary vars turn 1 one at a time depending upon value of $x$ and select the cost. Gurobi's indicator constraints will actually create linear constraints similar to 1-6 under the hood.

Comment: I see, I am going to try this idea and try to understand it better!  Definitely a new concept to me.  I will rate the answer once I figured it out!